# regex removing group of zeros

Tags: regex

i am in trouble with this problem: i have strings like this that i want to transform like this

`129.9000 --> 129.9`

`001.2345 --> 1.2345`

`101.2020 --> 101.202`

So basically i have to remove the starting zeros and the ending zeros before and after the [.]

How can i do with regex?

Thanks

Comment: What programming language? Most languages support format strings that help you do this without regex

Comment: If you're using Python and this is a string variable, just use `float(var)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easy for the first one (00012.234...) assuming your number is a string then, just use:

```
number = number.replace(/^0*(?=\d+\.)/g, "");
```

But for the second case (12.0000) we can't just use /0*$/g because it will strip 0 from number like  "12.". And I don't know how write regex for this case!
So I'll  write some logic for that.

```
let number = number.replace(/0*$/g, /\.0*$/.test(number) ? ".0" : "");
```

Comment: it works apart from the particular cases:

003.0000 --> 3.

which is bad, i would like a 3.0

000.2300 --> .23 is bad too, it has to be 0.23

Comment: Hey @Oliviero, I've fixed that bug in the updated solution!